# Vuetify, time-picker - how to set allowed time in 15 minutes intervals?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, intervals, timepicker

Im new in vuetify. Im trying to set the time in 15 minutes intervals and another options set as disabled. Anyone can help me to find a solution?
Code is here:

```
   v-model="time"
   :allowed-hours="allowedHours"
   :allowed-minutes="allowedMinutes"
   class="mt-4"
   format="24hr"
   scrollable
   min="9:30"
   max="22:15"
 ></v-time-picker>
 <v-time-picker
   v-model="timeStep"
   :allowed-minutes="allowedStep"
   class="mt-4"
   format="24hr"
 ></v-time-picker>


script>
export default {
 data () {
   return {
     time: '11:15',
     timeStep: '10:10',
   }
 },
 methods: {
allowedHours,
   allowedMinutes:,
   allowedStep: ,
 },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
<v-time-picker
   v-model="time"
   :allowed-minutes="allowedStep"
   format="24hr"
   scrollable
   min="9:30"
   max="22:15"
></v-time-picker>
```

And you can add the allowedStep method as follows:

```
methods: {
  allowedStep: m => m % 15 === 0,
},
```